# how for change fortran_compilers.props

Tags: compiler-construction, notepad

i want to add intel visual fortran compiler v11(IVF11) to installed version fortran of pscad v4.2 as i know must have change the fortran_compilers.props but i dont know about notepad programming i get this notepad code but i do'nt know how change to use :
(fortran_compilers.props:http://www.4shared.com/zip/EmJbcpYNba/fortran_compilers.html)

```
 <INTEL = "11.1" 
 version_key = "Compilers \ FORTRAN \ #, Major Version, Minor Version" 
 title_key = "Compilers \ FORTRAN \ # \ IA32, DisplayString" 
 batch_args = "ia32" BATCH_NAME = " ifortvars.bat "batch_path =" bin \ "exe_path_key ="                     Compilers \ FORTRAN \ #, ProductDir "exe_subpath =" bin \ ia32 " 
exe_name = "ifort.exe" 
EMTDC = "IF9"> </ INTEL>
```

As far as I know you can make changes to the code and add to fortran_compilers.props
thanks for your attention

Comment: Did you try to open the file `fortran_compilers.props`? How does it look like?

Comment: i open it with notepad/download [link:http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01354283681885928711] ///this code i write in the question it's a soloution but i don't how it work///link of soloution:[http://tech.cepsc.com/viewthread.php?tid=76921]

Comment: You can add the information to the question. You can also improve it in other ways. Consider using capital letters at least when starting sentences and in the word I.

Comment: Your links do not work, edit the question and make it more clear.

Comment: please help,I immediately need your help

Comment: Sorry, this is not how this site works. If you prepare your question well threre may be someone who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a PSCAD 4.6 installation, the `fortran_compiles.xml` contains:

```
<fortran_compilers ...>
    <!-- many lines omitted for brevity -->
    <compiler name="INTEL"  version="11.1"
              version_key="Compilers\FORTRAN\#,Major Version,Minor Version"
              title_key="Compilers\FORTRAN\#\IA32,DisplayString"
              exe_path_key="Compilers\FORTRAN\#,ProductDir"
              exe_subpath="bin\ia32"   exe_name="ifort.exe"   emtdc="if9"
              batch_path="bin\"   batch_name="ifortvars.bat"  batch_args="ia32"
              runtime_env="false"   title_suffix=""   compiler_type="x86"   registry="x86" />
    <!-- many more lines omitted for brevity -->
</fortran_compilers>
```

You may be able to use that to match the needs of the v4.2 `fortran_compiles.props` file.